Primitive non-central idempotents of a group algebra
Let $W_i;\ 1 \le i \le m$ be irreducible $\mathbb{C}$-representations of a finite group $G$ with $\mathbb{C}$-characters $\chi_i$. Let $(V,\rho$) be a $\mathbb{C}$-representation of $G$ with isotypic decomposition $V=W_1^{n_1}\oplus \cdots \oplus W_m^{n_m}$.
Consider a $\mathbb{CG}$-submodule $H_i$ of $W_i^{n_i}$ which is $\mathbb{CG}$-isomorphic to $\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{C}G}(W_i,W_i^{n_i})$.  Here, $\mathbb{C}G$ acts trivially on $\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{C}G}(W_i,W_i^{n_i})$. For every $f \in \text{Hom}_{\mathbb{C}G}(W_i,W_i^{n_i})$, $(g\cdot f)(x)=gf(g^{-1}x)=f(x)$, so $Hom_{\mathbb{C}G}(W_i,W_i^{n_i})$ is a $\mathbb{C}G$-module. We also have $W_i^{n_i} \cong H_i \otimes W_i$ as $\mathbb{C}G$-modules.
We have two types of projections:
1- The projection of $V$ onto $W_i^{n_i}$ is $\rho(e_i)$, where $e_i=\frac{\dim_{\mathbb{C}}(W_i)}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G}\chi_i(g^{-1})g$ is the central primitive idempotent in $\mathbb{C}G$ corresponding to $W_i$.
2- A projection of $V$ onto $H_i$ is $\rho(b_i)$, where $b_i$ is a primitive (non-central) idempotent in $\mathbb{C}Ge_i$.
I understand why $\rho(e_i)$ are projections, since $\mathbb{C}G=\mathbb{C}Ge_1 \times \cdots \times \mathbb{C}Ge_m$. However, I do not understand why $\rho(b_i)$ is a projection from $V$ onto $H_i$. I know $\rho(b_i)$ is a projection since $b_i$ is an idempotent, but I do not know why its image is $H_i$.
I am interested in $b_i$ since $\rho(b_i)\ -\ \rho(b_i)$ can recover a projection form $\text{End}_G(V) \cong \bigoplus_{i=1}^m M_{n_i}(\mathbb{C})$ onto $M_{n_i}(\mathbb{C})$.
Would you tell me how primitive non-central elements of $\mathbb{C}G$ are capable of inducing such projections?
